# keeping my array index within bounds - Python

Tags: python

I want to keep my index within array bounds. I am using an equation to add to my array index if something is already in that index. I would like for it to loop back around to the start if it were to add an amount to the current index that would cause it to be outside index bounds.

For example I have an Array `A = [[], [], [2], [3], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`
I try to add a value to `A[3]` but is has something in it already so I add 8 to the index value. This would make my index value 11 (which if indexed would give an error), but I would like for it to reach the last index and cycle back to start and add anything that may be left and insert to that index. In this case it would add to `A[0]`. So what ever is added to it, it will just keep looping back over and never index outside of range.

Comment: Use modulo to circle to 0. `my_list[idx%len(my_list)]`

Comment: so it is an error if the selected list already contains a value ?